# IBM Watson Analytics EXPLORE/PREDICT Service Public APIs?

Tags: ibm-watson

I have just started to learn the Watson analytics from [IBM Watson Analytics](https://watson.analytics.ibmcloud.com/) I have uploaded a csv file and used EXPLORE, PREDICT features. Is there anyway can I use these features using REST API? in Java. Is there any REST API available for this.? I don't know how to start exactly.

Comment: There is an API, see the answer in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337708/is-there-any-rest-apis-available-for-watson-analytics/

Answer (score 1):

The [REST APIs for Watson Analytics](https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog/) use OAuth2 for Authentication once you have a token you can upload data and navigate the folders.  There isn't a way to create Explorations and Predictions currently.  Below is a code snip from the [Java sample](https://github.com/WatsonAnalytics/oauth2-servlet) showing how you would get the user's profile information in Java.

```
    String apiURL = "https://" + WATSON_ANALYTICS_API_URL + WATSON_ANALYTICS_API_BASE_PATH + "/accounts/v1/me";
    HttpGet apiRequest = new HttpGet(apiURL);
    apiRequest.addHeader("X-IBM-Client-Id","client_id");
    apiRequest.addHeader("X-IBM-Client-Secret", "client_secret");
    apiRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKENS);
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse apiResponse = httpClient.execute( apiRequest );
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        apiResponse.getEntity().writeTo( stream );
        response.getWriter().write(stream.toString());
        stream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```